# How to keep DIV in same location while page is zoomed out

Tags: css, html

At 100% everything is fine because I get the height of the image slider which is 600px but since the slider is responsive, it changes its size and I would like to keep those six DIVS below it at all times.

The DIVS have `position: absolute` and `top: XXpx` to ensure it's below the slider at 100% zoom.

This is working so far, except I want to push it to the right a little:

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 650px; background-color: #FF0000; text-align: center;">
    <img src="theImages/shadow.png" alt="Shadow Footer" id="shadowImage" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" />
    <div style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; width 100%; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto; height: 150px; width: 265px; background-color: #F0F0FF;">
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto; height: 150px; width: 265px; background-color: #F0F000;">
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto; height: 150px; width: 265px; background-color: #00F0FF;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the body position to relative

Comment: Is there any way to set the inner DIV to not be centered without using position?

Comment: if you are using more then one div inside a div, then use float to left or right for position

Comment: I updated my question with some more detail. Now the three DIVs are showing correctly except Instead of being in the center using `margin: 0 auto;` I want to push them to the right a little. Any idea?

Comment: set position of both main div and body to relative

Comment: Its ok, all up to you. By the way thanks for upvote. :)

Comment: I meant, SO isn't allowing me to accept it until after some time... and you're welcome :D

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you have the DIVs set to `position:absolute`...they are staying the same place regardless of the page zoom. Perhaps [relative positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) may be what you need?

Comment: Under the slider there is a shadow DIV which displays the shadow image and it moves along with the size of the slider and that's what i am trying to do. I can show the html/css if need  be.

Answer (score -1):

```
#id div{
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-right:100px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:10px;    
    width:1400px;
}
```

You can make a div for all tags like body and change the width to be **100% of your page**. `margin` is just to make space between body and div.